# Google Drive API slower than the Documents List API

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I've recently migrated our webapp from GDocs to GDrive and I've noticed that even the `files.list` call takes about 3x longer (~2.5 seconds) than the corresponding Docs call.

This doesn't seem to depend on the size of the response (in fact Docs' XML is larger than Drive's JSON in my test). I've also experienced the same behaviour when doing simple requests via Google's OAuth Playground, so I'd rule out any local connectivity or library issues.

Is there any way to speed up the API calls?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Google Drive SDK documentation for performance tips:

https://developers.google.com/drive/performance

Tips include using gzip and partial response/update.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the issue isn't bandwidth but latency. Tiny responses take equally long. More than 2 seconds for a simple query isn't acceptable for us. Could this be a temporary issue?

Comment: It honestly sounds like a temporary issue to me, we haven't got other similar reports so far